# Linux Ram is not free eventhough the cpu is ~idle

Tags: linux

I'm newbie to linux.
My linux server says it has 47 gb Ram and quadcore cpu. But it is not as fast as it should be.

Used free -m command and it shows
Available: ~ 47gb
Used: ~ 45gb
Free: ~ 2gb

At that the server is not used by anyone else.
Used top command and it showed cpu is 0.1% used.

Is the used value shown in free command correct?

If the data is reliable what could make use of 45gb?

It is a fedora 64 bit kernel and it supports pae - physical address extension.

Please help and let me know if it is a known question.

Comment: Hmm isn't free -m going to show memory used in mb instead of gb?

Comment: And the huge 45 gb used, most probably they are the SWAP spaces. It could be that your SWAP allocation is messed up and physical memory has no issue

Comment: It showed in mb only. I just converted it readable. Also if I use free -g and free mem is less than 1 gb, it shows 0.

Comment: Another possibility is that your application(s) might have memory leak issue, or your applications' GC is not lazing around by not doing any work.

Comment: At that time no user application was running and only ssh was running. How to check if Swap allocation/config is ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a question, but the answer is, your memory is all there primarily free and not the source of your slowdowns. Take a look at your memory with free. For example:

```
$ free -tm
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3833       3751         82          0       1056       1107
-/+ buffers/cache:       1587       2246
Swap:         2000         83       1916
Total:        5833       3834       1999
```

In the first line `used` does **not** mean **currently in  use**.

Looking at the first line it says I have `3833 total` and have `3751 used`. Is that a problem? No. Why? When Linux uses memory, it marks the memory as used and when it is done, it releases the buffers and cached memory that is no longer needed. The memory that was used, but is now free is not returned to `total` and subtracted from `used`, rather the buffers and cache are simply returned to the system and are available for re-use by any other process that may need it.

If you look further to the right, you see I have `1056 buffers` and `1107 cached`. The next line explains that of the `total` there is only `1587 used` and `2246 free`. The `2246` roughly being the sum of the original `82 free` + (`1056 buffers` + `1107 cached`) that have been released for re-use. This is the **current** memory in use and available.

The next line shows the `swap` available and its use and the last line shows the rough sums of lines `1` and `3`. So no need to panic, if there is a slowdown, it is most likely not because your memory has all been used.

Comment: One more doubt. In my server the swap total 5 gb and Mem is 47 gb. Can swap be increased to get good performance? Because when comparing my server with a fast performing server, this value seems to be low.

Comment: No. If you are swapping your performance will be degraded due to the inefficiencies involved in paging memory out to disk. With 47G of memory, you are better off disabling swap altogether. When you check with `free -tm` or any other tool you will find your swap file is probably never touched. That is a **good** thing. You can turn swap off completely with ... `swapoff` and re-enable with `swapon`. Don't worry, without swap, even if you run out of 47G, you won't crash. Linux is smart enough to reserve memory for system operation, even when memory is exhausted. Good luck.